# Pandoc: Lua-Filter for replacing {{helloworld}} with <div>abc</div>

Tags: lua, pandoc

In the [manual](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#examples) I found this example of an pandoc lua-filter:

```
return {
  {
    Str = function (elem)
      if elem.text == "{{helloworld}}" then
        return pandoc.Emph {pandoc.Str "Hello, World"}
      else
        return elem
      end
    end,
  }
}
```

I want to replace `{{helloworld}}` with `<div>abc</div>`. My try:

```
return {
  {
    Str = function (elem)
      if elem.text == "{{helloworld}}" then
        return pandoc.RawInline('html','<div>abc</div>')
      else
        return elem
      end
    end,
  }
}
```

...but this give me the following output:

```
<p></p>
<div>abc</div>
<p></p>
```

How can I get rid of the empty `p`-tags?

**Additional information**

I convert from markdown to html and my markdown file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: try replacing `RawInline` with `RawBlock`, and `Str` with `Paragraph`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [manual](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#lua-filter-structure) says:

> The function’s output must result in an element of the same type as
>   the input. This means a filter function acting on an inline element
>   must return either nil, an inline, or a list of inlines, and a
>   function filtering a block element must return one of nil, a block, or
>   a list of block elements. Pandoc will throw an error if this condition
>   is violated.

You want your output to be rendered as a block (`<div>abc</div>`) but your input (`Str`) is inline. That's why it doesn't work. Change `Str` (Inline) to `Para` (Block), `elem.text` to `element.content[1].text` and `RawInline` to `RawBlock` and it will work:

```lua
return {
  {
    Para = function (elem)
      if elem.content[1].text == "{{helloworld}}" then
        return pandoc.RawBlock('html','<div>abc</div>')
      else
        return elem
      end
    end,
  }
}
```